# How can I see the pointer location, and simulate it?

Tags: screen, touchscreen, touch

I want to see the X and Y axis of my touch location in Android, and want to use the x and y axis by typing it into a shell extension, to simulate an actual touch on the screen. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

Go to

- Settings
- Developers Options
- In Input section check Show Pointer Location option.

If developer option is not enabled go to :

- Settings
- About Phone
- Click Build Number multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

To see the pointer: Settings > Developers Options > Show pointer location.