# Does Pixel 4 support three-finger swipe?

Tags: google-pixel, volume-control, gestures, google-pixel-4

Because the volume buttons no longer work, I want to assign three-finger swipe up and three-finger swipe down to increase and decrease the volume.

However, if the hardware doesn't support detecting more than two fingers, then there is no point in searching for an app to let me make this customization.

Answer (score 0):

**Google Pixel devices do support three-finger swipe, and possibly more.**

At the very least, the [TalkBack gesture customization](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6151827#zippy=%2Cversion-up) has three-finger swipes already set for moving the reading control

> #### Navigate your screen
>
> Version 9.1 & up
>
> | Action | One-finger gesture | Multi-finger gesture |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | ... | ... | ... |
> | Move to the next reading control | Up then down | 3-finger swipe down |
> | Move to the previous reading control | Down then up | 3-finger swipe up |
> | ... | ... | ... |

As for testing the limit, based on utilizing [How can I see the pointer location, and simulate it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/164295/44325), the touchscreen detects at least 10 pointers (5 left fingers + 5 right fingers).

---

<sup>Tested on Pixel 3a, which is the budget version of respective Pixel series</sup>